# How can I lock the FPS of CSGO to lower than 60?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

In *Counter-Strike: Global Offensive* `fps_max` can limit your FPS, but will only go down to 59. I know this is weird but I can't play on anything more than ~35 fps without getting sick. A lot of friends want me to play with them, but I can't at that high of an FPS

Does anyone have any ideas for how to lock the framerate under 60 FPS?

Comment: You might want to look into changing FoV instead, as **higher** framerate shouldn't make you feel sick, but the wrong FoV can.

Comment: I really agree with Chippies here; and actually, I would think a lower framerate wouldn't really help the problem; I know with VR, low FPS makes a lot of people sick.

Comment: Try creating an artificial bottleneck in your system. This might be crude, but a simple way would be to limit the power usage of your CPU to something like 70% (similar to using power saving mode). Although this may cause stuttering and and the system can overcome it's bottleneck, allowing it to surpass the frame rate you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of ways to do that but not from the game:

1. Use MSI Afterburner
2. Lower monitor to 30hz and force VSync
3. nVidia Inspector - It has an option Force Refresh Rate
4. Use Fraps and lock framerate (it has this option and it should be the simplest)